# Why does the call() method from web3.py cause a revert when combined with transfer()?

Tags: transactions, tokens, web3.py, python

I have deployed a contract for my custom ERC20 token.  I am trying to send tokens using web3.py

```
contract.functions.transfer(address, 20000000000000000000).call()
```

Above code is giving error
`raise ContractLogicError('execution reverted') web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted`

Same is the error for transferFrom() function. But it works totally fine with Remix IDE and metamask

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're using `.call()` method which is meant to be used when you **only** want to read the blockchain. If you want to write on the blockchain ( and usually `transfer` method means you want to transfer particular amount from one wallet to another which is basically writing on the blockchain ) then you have to use the `.transact()` method. In your case you need to change the code to:

```
contract.functions.transfer(address, 20000000000000000000).transact({"from": <YOUR_ADDRESS>})
```